# Style width selector of column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some trouble in a form which I am working on. Basically, I want to change the width of a column in md screen only, so I added in the class a selector called col-pvp, and than to only style the with in a specific size in boostrap.

I used this code:

```
.col-md-1.col-new{
    width: xxx;
 }
```

This way the width only changes in a column of 1 and md screen, but for some reason when it passed for example to mobile or tablet screen (xs, sm), the with of the column (col-new) doesn't go to his original size. I cannot figure out the problem.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 no-right-padding col-new">
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because you override bootstrap width and no matter what the screen resolution is your width will always override the bootstrap width since it comes after the bootstrap style. Put your code inside a media query like this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-1.col-new{
        width: ...
    }
}
```

That way your width only gets applied if screen is indeed md.

Comment: thanks, and it works, so i tried the same method but with a difference, for example i wanted to to the same thing, but applyting to sm, but when the resolution is in fact "md" the resolution is getting "sm", cant understand why.   @media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-sm) {.col-sm-3.col-cond {
      width: 22%;
    }}